# Laravel Middleware - how to execute inside a controller method?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using multiple views for the same URL, depending if the user is logged in or not.. so mywebsite.com is routed like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@redirector')->name('home');
```

The controller is this:

```
public function redirector(){

    if(!\Auth::check()){
        return view('welcome'); 
    }
    else{
        return $this->index();
    }

}
```

Now, when it runs the index function I need it to run the middleware 'auth', that updates and checks the user. The problem is, I cannot attach it to the route, since they might be unlogged causing a redirection loop. I tried this:

```
public function redirector(){

    if(!\Auth::check()){
        return view('welcome'); 
    }
    else{
        $this->middleware('auth');
        return $this->index();
    }

}
```

It does not run the middleware.

If I put it in the costructor method attaching it to index, like this:

```
 $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => 'index'])
```

it also won't run.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!\Auth::check()){..} //this returns false if a user is logged in, are you sure that's what you want?
```

If not then remove the '!'

You can also put the redirection logic in the middleware instead. If you are using the auth middleware that ships with Laravel this is already in place. You just have to modify it as below and place the middleware call in the constructor.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
   if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
       return redirect()->guest('login');
   }

   return $next($request);
}
```